# В настройках коммутатора нет параметров width, length!

Tags: сеть, маршрутизатор, cisco-packet-tracer

Делаю базовою настройку коммутатора.

Столкнулся с проблемой при установке параметров width, length

**Ввожу  команду:** `terminal length 24`. Пишет:

```
SW_50_21(config)#terminal length 24
                 ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

Есть задание установить это значение, но я не знаю как. 
Читал статьи, но у них все получается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте в **privileged mode**.

```
R7#terminat l? 
length 
R7#terminat w? 
width
```

Comment: так делал. пишет `SW_50_21#terminal l?
% Unrecognized command`. `#terminal?` - показывает только: `history, history,no`

Comment: А что за модель свитча? и какой IOS ?

Comment: Model: ws-c2960-24TT. ISO 12.2

Comment: Я делаю это в: `Cisco Packet Tracer`

Comment: попробуйте лучше EVE-NG, там хотя бы "настоящие" IOS. PacketTracer'ом пользовался много лет назад. Это же симулятор.

Comment: я не могу выбрать к сожалению( така лабораторная( будет без`width` значит(